# Topk of Minheap

Tags: algorithm

My application is most efficient if I keep datapoints in a minheap (A).  However, as an ending step, I want to output the TopK from A.

As a starting point, adding datapoints from A from back to front to another minheap (B), and once filled with K datapoints, reject datapoints less than the root will provide a TopK list in reverse order.

I'm wondering if I need to go thru A completely from back to front, or can I stop when I'm done with the row (meaning the tree depth) which has provided at least K datapoints?

I know that there are algorithms for converting a minheap to a maxheap, but I don't want the whole original heap sorted, but just the TopK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note there exists `priority deque` data structure (resembling diamond-shaped pair of heaps), but regular work with this structure is slower a bit (1.5 times AFAIR), so for seldom retrieving of TopK it is not good to use PD.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to consider the bottom log_2(K) complete rows.  Then you can stop, because each item closer than that to the root is less than K or more other items and cannot be in the top K.

This does not save you a lot of work, since at least half the items in the heap are leaves.

Comment: Thanks for this!  One optimization is to keep track of the max value in each complete row, which could allow stopping before going thru all log2(k) rows

Comment: On second thought, just flagging a row if any items contributed to the TopK is sufficient.  If none, then it it not necessary to continue thru the entire log2(K) complete rows.

Answer (score 0):

N=size of Minheap A based at 1

I think the most efficient algorithm is as follows:

1. Calculate a tentative TopK of the leaf nodes (N/2+1 to N) using the known algorithm of streaming TopK using Minheap B of size K (see, for example: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=122).
2. Identify the indices in A of the nodes that made the TopK, then recursively examine their parents to see if they make the TopK.  The depth of recursion is constrained by the index of the bottom log2(K) complete rows as Matt indicates above.

In practice, I've found that this generally examines N/2 + K nodes, although degenerate cases could go all the way down to examining the bottom log2(K) rows.